# How to think about solving $mg-\alpha x^2=m \ddot x$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider a hanging spring of negligible mass that does not obey Hooke's Law. It obeys another relationship: $F_s=-\alpha x^2,\alpha>0$. Attach a block of mass m to the spring (initially at equilibrium position, $x=0$) and release the block.

The question I have is how to calculate the time it takes to pass between two positions $x_1$ and $x_2$.

$2^{nd}$ Law gives us $mg-\alpha x^2=m \ddot x$

I have studied ordinary first and second order linear differential equations. This is nonlinear and I'd like to know what the steps would be to solve it.

In Maple, I have

```
ode := m*diff(x(t), t $ 2) + alpha*x(t)^2 - m*g = 0
dsolve(ode)
```

Which gives

[image: Solution to nonlinear ODE]

I am not sure what this means. Clearly I need to learn more about DE, but I'd like to have an idea now of how this would be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reduce the order of the DE:
$$mg-\alpha x^2=m \ddot x$$
$$2mg\dot x-2\alpha x^2\dot x=2m \dot x\ddot x$$
Integrate:
$$2mg x-\dfrac 23\alpha x^3=m \dot x^2+C_1$$
This is separable but the integral has no  closed form with elementary functions.

Comment: How would you get to the elliptic Weierstrass function?

Comment: It's separable then you have to integrate the root of a polynomial of degree three I guess this is why we have the Weierstrass function  @TymaGaidash

Comment: @TymaGaidash Take a look here at the diifferential equation on the Wiki page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_elliptic_function